# Adding p. or pp. in glossary based on number of pages

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to add the abbreviation p. or pp. before listing the pages in a glossary. My current MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{\emph{ pp.~}}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: MWE output]

Note that I redefine `\glspostdescription` to produce custom text instead of a dot.

This is *almost* what I want. The only thing I'd like to change to display p. when only a single page is being referenced, like in the example above. When there's a reference to multiple pages, I want to use pp. instead.

How can I accomplish this without manually editing all entries?